# How to change preference pane unlock dialog language?

Tags: macos

During the Mountain Lion installation I have selected the English language as the system language. However, the dialog asking for my password – that appears when you need to install an application, or when you want to unlock a preference pane – is in Dutch. I'm currently in The Netherlands, but I don't see how this might be related to the language of one type of dialog.

Here below an image of the dialog. As you can see there's even a mix of Dutch and English:
[image]

I haven't been to other countries yet with this MacBook Pro, so don't know if it's actually dependent on location.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem by removing all languages except English from the list found in `System Preferences -> Language & Text` and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same in Netherlands. I just switch the language once OSX  installation is complete (and before I run Migration Assistant).

Comment: Do you mean that you switch the language in the language and text pref panel? I have English as the first, and Dutch as the second. Removed Dutch from the list, but the problem persists. I have already used migration assistant to migrate from a SL install. I only migrated the User folder, not the settings.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I let the OSX install complete until I see the desktop, then I change the language setting in International preference pane and reboot.

Comment: I did this, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Everything still in Dutch despite language set to English? Even after reboot?

Comment: Try unselecting all languages (OSX selects some by default) except English, then cold boot.

Comment: No, not *everything* is in Dutch. That's why I'm surprised. Only the password dialog of some applications is partially in Dutch. And I cannot unselect all languages in the system prefs, the last one I want to unselect always stays.

Comment: Ah, are these apps not from Apple?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7332/discussion-between-bart-arondson-and-global-nomad)

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could try:

- Run `sudo languagesetup`, select a new language, and restart.
- Run `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist AppleLocale en_US` and restart.
- Run `sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Setup\ Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Setup\ Assistant`, go through the steps of creating a new account, restart, and delete the account.